# Work with values through Hashmap object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

i've got a HashMap:

```
Map<String, Object> ObjectMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I put a value to this map:

```
this.ObjectMap.put("text",new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Now map stores an object (ArrayList) with key "text".
And now i want to put a value to that ArrayList. I can do it this way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object> s= (List<Object>) ObjectMap.get("text"); s.add(new Ex("n"))
```

Can i do this better way and bypass annotation and parameters?

Comment: Sure, but you'll need to design a better, type-safe solution, instead of using a `Map<String,Object>`.  For example, writing an actual class with a field named `text` storing a `List<Ex>`.  Code mentioning `Object` is a warning sign in itself.

Comment: Waht do you mean by "bypassing *parameters*"?

Comment: What kind of object are you going to store as values in Map? If it is only of `List` of `Ex` you can use `Map<String, List<Ex>> map`. This will allow you to store `ArrayList<Ex>` like you already do, but this time you will be able to invoke `map.get("text").add(new Ex("n"))` without need to cast.

Comment: Want to store Primitive data types, unknown but same type.

Comment: Do you know *which* primitive data types?

Comment: No, it takes it from the configuration file. For example if i have 3 string fields, it stores String. If there are 3 numbers, it stores Integer and so on.

Comment: You can use a `Map<String,List<Object>>`, and add with `map.get("text").add(123)`

Comment: I know, but there is one problem, i want to put to the ObjectMap something else like HashMap

Comment: You could derive your own class from HashMap with a custom 'add' method. But this is certainly not a beautiful solution ether.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the configuration file you can use Stringified value in the list:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key", new ArrayList<String>());
List<String> list = map.get("key");
list.add("config");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont make value as an Object type its not recomended and causes confusion.

```jav
Map < String, List < String >> ObjectMap = new HashMap < String, List < String >> ();
this.ArrayObjectMap.put("text", new ArrayList < String > ());
ObjectMap.get("text").add("n");
```

Comment: I have Object there because behind Object i can have any data type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your use of `Object` as a type of a collection. The warning you are suppressing is there to let you know that this is generally not a good idea as it prevents Java's type system from preventing lots of subtle bugs.

The first thing to ask yourself is what objects you are putting into the collection and how will they be used when they are taken out. In most cases you will find that there is an `interface` you can define that all members can implement to explicitly declare what objects going into the collection must be able to do.

My recommendation is to look for that interface and then declare your map as `Map<String, MyInterface>`.